# ASP.NET Web Pages Cannot add new column to UserProfile table (SQL Server CE )

Tags: sql-server-ce, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

Using SQL Server CE, I am trying to add a new column to the `UserProfile` table in ASP.NET Web Pages but keep getting the error when attempting to save the database.

Any ideas?

> Database Manager
>
> The constraint cannot be removed because it is referenced by another constraint. [ Constraint name = UserProfile ]
>
> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException (0x80004005): The constraint cannot be removed because it is referenced by another constraint. [ Constraint name = UserProfile ]
>
> at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ProcessResults(Int32 hr)
>   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommandText(IntPtr&
>   pCursor, Boolean& isBaseTableCursor)
>   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method, ResultSetOptions options)
>   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>   at Microsoft.WebMatrix.DatabaseManager.SqlCeDatabase.SqlCeDatabaseProvider.DropTable(TableInfo
>   tableInfo, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction)
>   at Microsoft.WebMatrix.DatabaseManager.SqlCeDatabase.SqlCeDatabaseProvider.EditTable(String
>   connectionString, String schema, TableInfo tableInfo)
>   at Microsoft.WebMatrix.DatabaseManager.IisDbManagerModuleService.EditTable(DatabaseConnection
>   databaseConnection, String schema, Object tableInfoData, String
>   configPathState)
>   at Microsoft.WebMatrix.DatabaseManager.Client.ClientConnection.EditTable(String
>   schema, Object tableInfoData)
>   at Microsoft.WebMatrix.DatabaseManager.Client.ClientTable.CommitChanges()
>   at Microsoft.WebMatrix.DatabaseManager.Client.TableDesignerViewModel.PerformSave()

Comment: Opening and editing the database in Visual Studio works. Appears to be an issue only in WebMatrix. Would be interested to know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sean,

It's a known bug in WebMatrix 2.0RC code. I found a quick workaround, add a row of data, then add your column.

Typically the place to report this kind of issue is at: webmatrix.uservoice.com

Cheers,
Yishai